# Amazon SPAPI: BuyerInfo Remains Empty Despite RDT

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

My objective is to develop an application that retrieves orders and customer data from Amazon.
I submitted a request to Amazon for access to information such as customer addresses and shipping details, which was approved, granting me a Restricted Data Token (RDT). However, I am encountering an issue where the RDT token is not providing the desired customer address and shipping information.

```
curl --location 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/tokens/2021-03-01/restrictedDataToken' \
--header 'x-amz-access-token: {myToken}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
      "restrictedResources": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/orders/v0/orders",
      "dataElements": {"buyerInfo": "", "shippingAddress": ""}
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using `"dataElements": ["buyerInfo", "shippingAddress"]` but the problem still persist.

To retrieve my orders, I use the following endpoint:

```
curl --location 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders?MarketplaceIds=A13V1IB3VIYZZH&CreatedAfter=2023-09-04' \
--header 'x-amz-access-token: {myRDT}'
```

However, the resulting payload shows empty BuyerInfo and no shipping address:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "Orders": [
      {
        "BuyerInfo": {},
        "AmazonOrderId": "171-1216727-6611533",
        "EarliestShipDate": "2023-09-07T22:00:00Z",
        "SalesChannel": "Amazon.fr",
        "AutomatedShippingSettings": {
          "HasAutomatedShippingSettings": false
        }
        // ... Additional order details
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Would you have any ideas please ?